# why data is not inserting in db any thing wrong in code

Tags: java

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autosave", "root", "");

PreparedStatement pstmt;
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `saver` WHERE 1");
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE `saver` SET `post_id`=?,`post_title`=?,`post_description`=?,`post_status`=?, WHERE 1");

String q = ("INSERT into saver(post_id,post_title,post_description,post_status) " +
"values('" + id + "','" + title + "'," + description + ",'" + status + "')");

pstmt.executeUpdate();
out.println(" done").
```

Comment: **Never** use string concatenation to fill in SQL values. [Let me introduce you to my friend Bobby...](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: If you could add a very small explanation of what the code does, it would be great, since SO does not like answers with only code

Answer (score 0):

You have three separate bits of SQL there.

Your first one (the `SELECT`) is never run because you immediately replace what's in `pstmt` on the very next line.

Your second one (the `UPDATE`) has placeholders for parameters, but you never fill in those parameters (via `pstmt.setInt`, `pstmt.setString` etc.), so calling `executeUpdate` on it should fail with an error.

Your third one (the `INSERT`) is just a string you never do anything with (which is good, because it uses string concatenation to fill in the values, which is never a good idea, it leaves your code open to SQL Injection attacks, both intentional and [unintentional](https://bobby-tables.com/)).

You also have a syntax error right at the end, a `.` instead of a `;`.

I don't know what RDBMS you're using, but most of the ones I've used don't allow a comma after the last item in the `SET` clause, so you probably want to remove that last comma.

Note that the `UPDATE` used backticks to quote the table and column names, but your `INSERT` code doesn't. I recommend being consistent.

Here's an example of doing the `UPDATE` with the variables you used in the code:

```
try (
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE `saver` " +
        "SET `post_id`=?,`post_title`=?,`post_description`=?,`post_status`=? " +
        "WHERE 1"
    );
) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, id);
    pstmt.setString(2, title);
    pstmt.setString(3, description);
    pstmt.setString(4, status);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    out.println(" done");
}
```

(That's a try-with-resources statement, used so that regardless of how the code leaves that block — error or success — the statement is released.)

Or if you wanted to do the `INSERT` instead, it would be largely the same, just different SQL:

```
try (
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO `saver` (`post_id`, `post_title`, `post_description`, `post_status`) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    );
) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, id);
    pstmt.setString(2, title);
    pstmt.setString(3, description);
    pstmt.setString(4, status);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    out.println(" done");
}
```